# At what reputation can you see who downvoted your posts?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

Is this feature even available?

I'm just asking, not suggesting a feature, please do not vote me down. You guys [scare](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_phobia_of_unicorns_called) me.

Comment: Looking at the question that got down voted, I don't see a comment about explaining why, but my guess would be the lack of capitalization, correct punctuation, and format of the question.

Answer (score 16):

No matter how much rep you have, you cannot see who cast votes on posts (votes are anonymous).

Answer (score 8):

There is no way you can see who cast the vote as a normal user. And as I remember correctly, even moderators can't see them (only those with direct access to the database).

If votes were not anonymous, there would be a lot of revenge downvoting which is bad because we need to focus on the content not on the author.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see, as the others already said, and that's the reason that when you cast downvote there is big orange alert saying something along the lines of "Please add comment explaining why you did that". That orange alert go away at some point though (2K rep I think).

Those casing downvotes without leaving comments are either "cowards" who fear revenge (though it's pretty rare IMO) or if there's already comment of previous downvote, no need to repeat same comment.

Just curious.... what unicornaphobia has to do with that? :p