# Strange doubt regarding privacy of voting system in SE sites

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

I'm afraid this question maybe closed, even then I am trying to get answer for this strange doubt. Are Up Voting or Down Voting really anonymous? Or is there any role who can see who and  all up voted and who and all downvoted? Just got a doubt

Comment: You are asking because you just serial downvote someone and don't want to be unmasked? :)

Comment: also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74045/at-what-reputation-can-you-see-who-downvoted-your-posts amongst a whole host of other duplicates.

Comment: @j0k, why should I serially down vote someone purposefully?

Comment: @PradeepSimha I don't know, I'm just asking.

Comment: @j0k, I have down-voted only low quality questions. In-fact you can verify them :)

Comment: Someone downvoted, ha ha proving privacy of voting systems.. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The developers can see it, if they really wanted to, because they have access to the raw data.

Otherwise, no one. Not even Moderators.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, votes are anonymous, in so far as humans don't <sup>1</sup> see them. However, be warned: if anyone tries to pull monkey business like sockpuppet voting or serial voting, it is likely to be identified by automated scripts and possibly bring you unwanted attention from the mods.

[image]

So basically, each individual vote is anonymous, but suspicious patterns in a user's voting will be identified.

<sup>1. The operative word here is don't, not **can't**. Your votes are still associated with you in the system.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Certain SE employees can see individual votes, so they can determine exactly who voted for whom and on which post.

Moderators can see certain vote patterns, mostly related to dealing with vote fraud. This can mean that a moderator can see who you voted for under certain circumstances, but moderators can never see which posts you have voted on. The data moderators can see is always in aggregates, not on a single post basis.